# snowflake query is taking too much time to run

Tags: sql, join, optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lateral-join

```
SELECT 
    category_tree_master__."category_id" AS category_id,
    --searchchildrenmaster.children,
    --ARRAY_CONTAINS(category_product_nb_stand_nb_product."category_id" ::varchar:: VARIANT ,TO_ARRAY(SPLIT(CAST(searchchildrenmaster."category_id" AS VARCHAR) || COALESCE (', ' || searchchildrenmaster.children, ''), ','))) AS check_,
    --category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.stands AS nb_stands,
    --category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.products AS nb_products
    COUNT(DISTINCT category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.stands) OVER (PARTITION BY category_tree_master__."category_id"),
    COUNT(DISTINCT category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.products) OVER (PARTITION BY category_tree_master__."category_id")
    --IFF (count (DISTINCT category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.stands)  IS NOT NULL , count (DISTINCT category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.stands) , 0) AS nb_stands,
    --IFF (count (DISTINCT category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.products)  IS NOT NULL , count (DISTINCT category_product_nb_stand_nb_product.products) , 0) AS nb_products
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         src."category_id",
         CAT_CHILDREN_LIST AS children
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."category_tree_master_id", 
              EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."category_id"
          FROM 
              EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master
          INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT 
                   EXPO_MASTER.category_lang."category_id",  
                   EXPO_MASTER.category_lang."lang"
               FROM 
                   EXPO_MASTER.category_lang
               WHERE 
                   EXPO_MASTER.category_lang."lang" = 'fr') AS tmp
            ON EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."category_id" = tmp."category_id") src
            LEFT JOIN PERFORMANCE.SEARCH_CHILDREN_MASTER  children_cat
                ON CHILDREN_CAT."category_id"  = src."category_id" ) searchchildrenmaster
        INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT 
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."category_tree_master_id", 
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."category_id", 
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."parent_id",
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."gauche", 
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."droite", 
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."niveau", 
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master_ref_plateforme_selection."selection_leadgen",
          EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master_ref_plateforme_selection."selection_stand"
        FROM 
            EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master
        JOIN 
            EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master_ref_plateforme_selection 
            ON 
            (
                EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master_ref_plateforme_selection."category_tree_master_id" = EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."category_tree_master_id" AND 
                EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master_ref_plateforme_selection."ref_plateforme_id" = 1
            )
        )category_tree_master__ ON category_tree_master__."category_id" = 
        CASE WHEN searchchildrenmaster."category_id" IS NOT NULL THEN searchchildrenmaster."category_id" ELSE 1 END
         LEFT JOIN LATERAL
         (
            SELECT
              EXPO_MASTER.category_product."category_id",
              EXPO_MASTER.product."stand_id" AS stands,
              EXPO_MASTER.product."product_id" AS products
            FROM 
                EXPO_MASTER.category_product
            JOIN 
                EXPO_MASTER.product ON (EXPO_MASTER.product."product_id" = EXPO_MASTER.category_product."product_id")
                WHERE 
                ARRAY_CONTAINS(EXPO_MASTER.category_product."category_id" ::varchar:: VARIANT ,TO_ARRAY(SPLIT(CAST(searchchildrenmaster."category_id" AS VARCHAR) || COALESCE (', ' || searchchildrenmaster.children, ''), ',')))
                    )category_product_nb_stand_nb_product
                --GROUP BY category_tree_master__."category_id"
```

I'm using this query to count the number of stands and the number of products of each category in the `EXPO_MASTER.category_tree_master."category_id"` where `EXPO_MASTER.category_product` is in the a list of values.

That's the query, I tried selecting columns without aggregation it works fine but when i try to do the COUNT with partition by or group by the Query takes for ever to run (around 6-8 minutes).

Can someone please tell me what the problem is, and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the EXPLAIN for your query, using the most readable format

Comment: You have given only the barest sketch of what you'd like to have happen and no description or examples of the data you are operating on.  This leaves us with trying to disassemble your SQL to see what it does, but even there your parentheses and indentation don't match and the use of more exotic features (lateral joins with arrays) makes it difficult to discern your intent.  I suspect there is a much more straightforward solution to your problem, but I don't want to spend >1 hour figuring out your intent.  Judging by the lack of answers here I think others feel the same.

Comment: Your query has way too many sub-selects where a simple join would suffice.  I'd attempt to fix your query, but I don't know inputs, desired outputs, or how large your datasets are.  Query performance can depend on appropriately sized warehouses, as well.  If adding a window function to this severely changes your performance, it could be because your warehouse is too small to do the necessary ordering.  Look for remote disk spilling in your query profile.  If you see some, make your warehouse larger.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer sorry this is my first post the use case is transforming a talend job into a snowflake view i have multiple lookups and outputs from procedures (in sourceid,out arbo_source) the arbo_source is the tree structure, i've created views that simulate these procedures but without any parameters they return the a table for every sourceid the table name is searchchildenmaster.
in the job i have 3 lookups from tables that takes a globalmapkey as parameter and these lookups are cartesian

Comment: exemple of a query in a lookup"
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT product.stand_id) as nb_stands,
  COUNT(DISTINCT product.product_id) as nb_products
FROM 
 " + context.connection_Mysql_Database + ".category_product
JOIN 
" + context.connection_Mysql_Database + ".product ON (product.product_id = category_product.product_id)
WHERE 
 category_product.category_id  IN (" + globalMap.get("category_id") + ")
"

Comment: this is the globalMap.get("category_id") =  searchchildrenmaster.category_id + (!Relational.ISNULL(searchchildrenmaster.children) && !searchchildrenmaster.children.equals("") ? ", " + searchchildrenmaster.children : "")  so i have to check for every category_product."category_id" if it exists in globalMap.get("category_id")

Answer (score 0):

ok lets first rewrite the SQL to be just a little more readable to me, I will rename things from double quoted to normal and point out unused columns, those IFF's can be swapped for zeroifnull, and lets use some readable size aliases (just to keep it all flowing):

```
SELECT 
    ctm_.category_id
    --,scm.children,
    --,ARRAY_CONTAINS(cp_s_p.category_id ::varchar::variant ,  scm.array_of_ids  ) AS check_
    --,cp_s_p.stands AS nb_stands
    --,cp_s_p.products AS nb_products
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT cp_s_p.stands) OVER (PARTITION BY ctm_.category_id)
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT cp_s_p.products) OVER (PARTITION BY ctm_.category_id)
    --,zeroifnull(count (DISTINCT cp_s_p.stands)) AS nb_stands
    --,zeroifnull(count (DISTINCT cp_s_p.products)) AS nb_products
FROM (
    SELECT 
        src.category_id,
        NVL(src.category_id, 1) as category_id_or_one,
        cc.cat_children_list AS children,
        SPLIT( scm."category_id"::VARCHAR || COALESCE (', ' || scm.children, ''), ',') as array_of_ids
     FROM (
        SELECT 
            --ctm_a."category_tree_master_id" AS category_tree_master_id, /* not used in scm select */
            ctm_a."category_id" AS category_id
        FROM expo_master.category_tree_master AS ctm_a
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                cl."category_id" AS category_id  
                --cl."lang" AS lang /* this was not used */
            FROM expo_master.category_lang AS cl
            WHERE cl."lang" = 'fr'
        ) AS tmp
            ON ctm_a.category_id = tmp.category_id
    ) AS src
    LEFT JOIN performance.search_children_master AS cc
        ON cc."category_id"  = src.category_id
) as scm /*searchchildrenmaster*/
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        -- ctm_b."category_tree_master_id" /* not used */
        ctm_b."category_id" as category_id /*,*/ 
        --ctm_b."parent_id", /* not used */
        --ctm_b."gauche", /* not used */
        --ctm_b."droite", /* not used */
        --ctm_b."niveau", /* not used */
        --ctmrps."selection_leadgen", /* not used */
        --ctmrps."selection_stand"  /* not used */
    FROM expo_master.category_tree_master as ctm_b 
    JOIN expo_master.category_tree_master_ref_plateforme_selection as ctmrps
        ON ctmrps."category_tree_master_id" = ctm_b."category_tree_master_id" 
            AND ctmrps."ref_plateforme_id" = 1
) as ctm_ /*category_tree_master__ */
    ON ctm_.category_id = scm.category_id_or_one
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        cp."category_id" as category_id,
        p."stand_id" AS stands,
        p."product_id" AS products
    FROM expo_master.category_product AS cp
    JOIN EXPO_MASTER.product AS p 
        ON p."product_id" = cp."product_id"
    WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(cp."category_id" ::varchar::variant , scm.array_of_ids)
) as cp_s_p /*category_product_nb_stand_nb_product*/
--GROUP BY ctm_.category_id
```

I would be VERY inclined to change from the ARRAY_CONTAINS to FLATTENing that "array" and doing a normal equi-join on that, and perhaps throw in a couple of DISTINCTs on the sub-selects to avoid known duplicate explosion's:

```
SELECT 
    ctm_.category_id
    --,scm.children,
    --,cp_s_p.stands AS nb_stands
    --,cp_s_p.products AS nb_products
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT cp_s_p.stands) OVER (PARTITION BY ctm_.category_id)
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT cp_s_p.products) OVER (PARTITION BY ctm_.category_id)
    --,zeroifnull(count (DISTINCT cp_s_p.stands)) AS nb_stands
    --,zeroifnull(count (DISTINCT cp_s_p.products)) AS nb_products
FROM (
    SELECT 
        src.category_id,
        NVL(src.category_id, 1) as category_id_or_one,
        --cc.cat_children_list AS children,
        try_to_number(trim(s.value)) as split_ids
     FROM (
        SELECT 
            ctm_a."category_id" AS category_id
        FROM expo_master.category_tree_master AS ctm_a
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                cl."category_id" AS category_id
            FROM expo_master.category_lang AS cl
            WHERE cl."lang" = 'fr'
        ) AS tmp
            ON ctm_a.category_id = tmp.category_id
    ) AS src
    LEFT JOIN performance.search_children_master AS cc
        ON cc."category_id"  = src.category_id
    ,,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE( src.category_id::VARCHAR || COALESCE (',' || cc.cat_children_list, ''), ',') as s
) as scm /*searchchildrenmaster*/
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ctm_b."category_id" as category_id
    FROM expo_master.category_tree_master as ctm_b 
    JOIN expo_master.category_tree_master_ref_plateforme_selection as ctmrps
        ON ctmrps."category_tree_master_id" = ctm_b."category_tree_master_id" 
            AND ctmrps."ref_plateforme_id" = 1
) as ctm_ /*category_tree_master__ */
    ON ctm_.category_id = scm.category_id_or_one
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        cp."category_id" as category_id,
        p."stand_id" AS stands,
        p."product_id" AS products
    FROM expo_master.category_product AS cp
    JOIN EXPO_MASTER.product AS p 
        ON p."product_id" = cp."product_id"
) as cp_s_p /*category_product_nb_stand_nb_product*/
    ON cp_s_p.category_id = scm.split_ids
--GROUP BY ctm_.category_id
```

Comment: ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE( scm."category_id"::VARCHAR || COALESCE (',' || cc.cat_children_list, ''), ',') as s
can i use scm in this expression even though the alias of scm is after this ? 
and can you please explain to me what flatten does exactly

Comment: i go this error when i did this 
,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE( src."category_id"::VARCHAR || COALESCE (',' || children_cat.cat_children_list, ''), ',') as s
the error : SQL Error [2031] [42601]: SQL compilation error:
Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Comment: to be fair, I did not run this, just edit in np++, but that should have been `,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE( src.category_id::VARCHAR || COALESCE (',' || cc.cat_children_list, ''), ',') as s`